# Drupal 7 pass multiple fields

Tags: drupal-7, field

How I can pass multiple field values through `$data` and render them using `$items`.

**Please see the below code snippet:**

```
function custom_block_view($delta = '') {
global $user;
$account = $user;
$block['content'] = t('Hello @user from IP @host',array(
'@user' => format_username($user),
'@host' => $account->hostname
));

$result = db_select('node','a')
->fields('a', array('title', 'nid', 'status'))
->execute();

foreach($result as $node) {
$items[] = array(
  'data' => t($node->title)
   );
}

$block['content'] .= theme('item_list', array(
'items' => $items
));

return $block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the how to pass another value through `$data`. Just adding a simple concatenation symbol (.)

Please check the below snippet.

```
foreach($result as $node) {
$items[] = array(
  'data' => t($node->title).t($node->nid)
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use renderable array or string containing rendered HTML content.

content: The content of the block's body. This may be a **renderable array (preferable)** or a **string containing rendered HTML content**.

You can refer this link for more info:

[hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)

[Drupal 7 Render Arrays](http://randyfay.com/node/79)

Altering

Both blocks and pages can be altered just as forms have been alterable for some time. Many other types are also alterable. With hook_page_alter() we can do things like this:

```
function mymodule_page_alter(&$page) {
  // Move search form into the footer.
  $page['footer']['search_form'] = $page['sidebar_first']['search_form'];
  unset($page['sidebar_first']['search_form']);

  // Remove the "powered by Drupal" block
  unset($page['footer']['system_powered-by']);
}
```